# Setup and connect to database for Django on AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

I've currently hosted a Django application on EC2 using Apache.

My database engine

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'subscribe',
        'USER': '<username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

After setting up Apache, i can now access my web application on the public IP but I cannot perform any DB transcations as the tables don't exist. This is the error message:

```
ProgrammingError at /some-url
(1146, "Table 'subscribe.subscriberapp_subscriber' doesn't exist")
```

I know for sure this is because no migrations have been made post deploying to AWS. My question is, how do I setup the DB completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the initial migrations to create the tables. From the console verify that you have a connection to your db by running `./manage.py dbshell`. If that works, you have the connection.

Then you need to either run the initial `./manage.py syncdb` (for django <1.7) or if you're running django 1.7+ you will run `./manage.py migrate`